# show that torus is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am having difficuties in showing a torus is compact. Initially I wanted to use Heine-Borel theorem, but after that I realise we are not working in $\mathbb{R}^n$ space. So a simple way to show torus is compact is by definition. But after defining an open cover for torus, I don't know how to proceed. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: How is your torus defined? $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$? $\mathbb{S}^n$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I guess you meant $(S^1)^n$.

Comment: $T=[0,1] \times [0,1]$ under the equivalence relation $(0,x_2)$ ~ $(1,x_2)$ for all $x_2 \in [0,1]$ and $(x_1,0)$ ~ $(x_1,1)$ for all $x_1 \in [0,1]$

Comment: The product of compact spaces is compact.

Comment: @user43208 I only write $\mathbb{S}$ for $S^1$. But I guess I shouldn't expect others to know that.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I don't have that result.

Comment: @Idonknow Okay, that's equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$, though in a way even easier. Can you find a continuous map from $[0,1]^2$ onto the torus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are thinking of the torus as $S^1 \times S^1$:

1. Products of compact sets are compact (you only need the finite case)
2. $S^1$ compact (as it is a closed and bounded subset of $R^2$).

If you are thinking of the torus as $R^2 / Z^2$:

1. This quotient map makes the same identifications as the exponential map $(e^{2 \pi i x}, e^{2 \pi i y})$, so since both are quotients $R^2 / Z^2$ is homeomorphic to $S^1 \times S^1$. (You will have to prove that if $q_1: X \to Y_1$ and $q_2 : X \to Y_2$ are quotient maps, and $q_1(x) = q_1(x')$ iff $q_2(x) = q_2(x')$, then $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are (naturally) homeomorphic.)

Comment: Or you show that $\mathbb{R}^2/ \mathbb{Z}^2$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]^2$ whith identifications on opposite sides..

Answer (score 5):

If $X$ is compact then the quotient space $X/\sim $ is compact.  Proof.  The quotient map $p : X \to X /\sim, \ x \mapsto [x]_{\sim}$, is surjective and continuous by definition.

As you've heard the product of compact spaces is compact.

Comment: Brillant. So I can also prove klein bottle is compact using this quotient map?

Comment: Don't know about that.  How is the Klein Bottle defined?

Comment: I think $X$ is the same as in torus just that the plane model for Klein bottle has different orientation compared to torus.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to show that $T=[0,1]^2/\sim$ is homeomorphic to one of the other definitions of the torus, which are obviously compact. One such possible equivalent definition is $S^1\times S^1$.

Alternatively, let $\phi:[0,1]^2\rightarrow T$ be the quotient map. Take an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $T$. Then $\{\phi^{-1}(U_\alpha)\}$ is an open cover of $[0,1]^2$, which is compact. Thus there exist a finite subcover $\{\phi^{-1}(U_k)\}_{k=1}^n$ of $[0,1]$. Then $\{U_k\}_{k=1}^n$ is a finite subcover of $\{U_\alpha\}$ for $T$.

Notice that this proof works for the general statement: the quotient of a compact space is compact.

Comment: Regarding the quotient map method, is quotient map always continuous? Because from what I see in your solution, you seem to assume that quotient map is continuous and hence preserve compactness.

Comment: @Idonknow The topology on a quotient is always the *strongest* (i.e. the one with most opens) topology for which the quotient map is continuous. You can try to prove that, it's a good exercise.